# Simplifying algebra fraction expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The below equation is after taking the derivative for a calculus problem, but when I  try to simplify I don't see how. My calculator shows that
$${5(\sqrt{1+x^2}-x) \over \sqrt{1+x^2}(1+(x-\sqrt{1+x^2})^2)}$$ simplifies to 
$${5 \over 2(x^2+1)}$$
and no matter how much I rearrange the equation I just don't see how anything cancels. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried expanding the denominator and then multiplying the numerator and denominator by the conjugate?

Comment: Multiply out the bracket in the denominator, and see what happens. If that doesn't work, feel free to comment again (with your result). Tons of stuff will cancel if you do it right.

Comment: I have not tried the conjugate, i will try that now, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sqrt{1+x^2}(1+(x-\sqrt{1+x^2})^2) \\ =\sqrt{1+x^2}+x^2\sqrt{1+x^2}+\sqrt{1+x^2}(1+x^2)-2x(\sqrt{1+x^2})^2 \\ =2\sqrt{1+x^2}+2x^2\sqrt{1+x^2}-2x(1+x^2) \\ = (2+2x^2)\sqrt{1+x^2}-2x(1+x^2) \\ = 2(1+x^2)\left[\sqrt{1+x^2}-x\right]$$

Then cancel from the numerator and denominator to get your result.

Comment: this seems quite promising, I'm going to see if i understand it

Comment: Ha, I had gotten somewhere close to line 4, but there's no way i would have figured out from line 4 to line 5 on my own. I'm going to have to practice large polynomial factoring's i guess. Thanks!

Comment: this is actually incredibly helpful to see when you decided to multiply things out and when you didn't. I immediately was multiplying everything out and kept getting $2x^3$ and that was throwing me off